# Python tkinter "KeyError: <class __main__." error

Tags: python, tkinter

I am relatively new to tkinter. I created this application and it ran perfectly fine. Then I added the HelpPage class and it gave me this error "KeyError: " I removed the HelpPage class and the same error showed up as main.PageTwo. I cannot seem to get it to run anymore.

Here is the code (the functions are all indented properly even though it doesn't show up):

```
## This program calculates the number of pixels which need to be removed from each edge of collected images based on camera paramters and measured distances

## horizontal_field_of_view = camera_distance*(sensor_width/focal_length) where sensor_width is the horizontal width. Sensor_width and focal_length are measured in mm and camera distance is measure in m
## resolution = horizontal_field_of_view/number_of_pixels where horizontal_field_of_view is measured in m. The results is the width of a single pixel measured in m.


import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog
import os

class Application(tk.Tk):

    PixSize=0
    cnt=1
    height=0
    width=0
    NumPixX=0
    NumPixY=0
    NumImages=0
    file='none'

def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand = True)

    container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

    self.frames={}

    for F in (StartPage,PageOne,PageTwo,PageThree,FinalPage,HelpPage):
        frame = F(container,self)
        self.frames[F]= frame
        frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame(StartPage)
    ## opens the file all the data will be stored in

def selectfolder(self):
    folder=tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile()
    self.file=folder
    self.show_frame(PageOne)

def show_frame(self,controller):

    frame=self.frames[controller]
    frame.tkraise()

def rescalc(self,argCamDist,argSenWidth,argFocLen,argNumPix,cont): ## runs both equations for calculating spatial resolution   
    ## part one: calculating HFOV
    HFOV = float(argCamDist.get())*(float(argSenWidth.get())/float(argFocLen.get()))
    ## part two: calculating PixSize
    self.PixSize = float(argNumPix.get())/HFOV
    cont.show_frame(PageThree)

def GetNumbers(self,argNumImages,argNumPixX,argNumPixY,cont):
    self.NumPixX=int(argNumPixX.get())
    self.NumPixY=int(argNumPixY.get())
    self.NumImages=int(argNumImages.get())
    cont.file.write(str(self.NumImages))
    cont.show_frame(PageTwo)

def ClipCalculator(self,argLabel,argtop,argleft,argbottom,argright,argNumPixX,argNumPixY,argNumImages,argLabel3,argLabel4,cont):
    ## calculates the number of pixels to be removed from each direction and writes it to a file
    upper=int(self.PixSize*float(argtop.get()))+1
    left=int(self.PixSize*float(argleft.get()))+1
    if cont.cnt==1:
        bottom=int(argNumPixY)-(int(self.PixSize*float(argbottom.get()))+1)
        right=int(argNumPixX)-(int(self.PixSize*float(argright.get()))+1)
        cont.width=right-left
        cont.height=upper-bottom
    else:
        bottom=upper+cont.height
        right=left+cont.width    
    cont.file.write('upper left: rows:{0}:columns:{1} \n'.format(upper,left))
    cont.file.write('upper right: rows:{0}:columns:{1} \n'.format(upper,right))
    cont.file.write('lower left: rows:{0}:columns:{1} \n'.format(bottom,left))
    cont.file.write('lower right: rows:{0}:columns:{1} \n'.format(bottom,right))
    cont.cnt+=1
    ##updates label and resets entry windows to default then refreshes Page
    argLabel['text']="Image Number {0}".format(cont.cnt)
    argtop.delete(0,tk.END)
    argtop.insert(0,"0.0")
    argleft.delete(0,tk.END)
    argleft.insert(0,"0.0")
    argbottom.delete(0,tk.END)
    argbottom.insert(0,"0.0")
    argright.delete(0,tk.END)
    argright.insert(0,"0.0")
    cont.refresh(argbottom,argright,argLabel3,argLabel4,cont)

def refresh(self,Label3,Label4,entry3,entry4,cont):
    if cont.cnt==1:
        cont.show_frame(PageTwo)
    if (cont.cnt > 1 and cont.cnt <= cont.NumImages):
        Label3.forget()
        Label4.forget()
        entry3.forget()
        entry4.forget()
        cont.show_frame(PageTwo)
    else:
        cont.file.close()
        cont.show_frame(FinalPage)
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    label=tk.Label(self,text="Image Overlap Program V 1.0")
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Help", command=controller.show_frame(HelpPage))
    button1.pack()
    button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Select Folder", command=lambda: controller.selectfolder())
    button2.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)


    label3=tk.Label(self,text="Camera Parameters")
    label3.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    label1=tk.Label(self,text="Camera Distance").pack()
    entry1=tk.Entry(self)
    entry1.insert(0,"0.0")
    entry1.pack()

    label2=tk.Label(self,text="Sensor Width").pack()
    entry2=tk.Entry(self)
    entry2.insert(0,"0.0")
    entry2.pack()

    label3=tk.Label(self,text="Focal Length").pack()
    entry3=tk.Entry(self)
    entry3.insert(0,"0.0")
    entry3.pack()

    label4=tk.Label(self,text="Number Of Pixels").pack()
    entry4=tk.Entry(self)
    entry4.insert(0,"0.0")
    entry4.pack()

    button1=tk.Button(self,text='run',command = lambda: controller.rescalc(entry1,entry2,entry3,entry4,controller))
    button1.pack()

    button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button3.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    cont=controller

    argNumPixX= cont.NumPixX
    argNumPixY= cont.NumPixY
    argNumImages= cont.NumImages

    title=tk.Label(self,text="Distance Parameters")
    title.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    Label5=tk.Label(self,text="Image Number {0}".format(cont.cnt))
    Label5.pack()

    Label1=tk.Label(self,text="How many m of the image needs to be removed from the top")
    Label1.pack()
    entry1=tk.Entry(self)
    entry1.insert(0,"0.0")
    entry1.pack()

    Label2=tk.Label(self,text="How many m of the image needs to be removed from the left")
    Label2.pack()
    entry2=tk.Entry(self)
    entry2.insert(0,"0.0")
    entry2.pack()

    Label3=tk.Label(self,text="How many m of the image needs to be removed from the bottm")
    Label3.pack()
    entry3=tk.Entry(self)
    entry3.insert(0,"0.0")
    entry3.pack()

    Label4=tk.Label(self,text="How many m of the image needs to be removed from the right")
    Label4.pack()
    entry4=tk.Entry(self)
    entry4.insert(0,"0.0")
    entry4.pack()

    button1=tk.Button(self,text="Run1",command= lambda: controller.ClipCalculator(Label5,entry1,entry2,entry3,entry4,argNumPixX,argNumPixY,argNumImages,Label3,Label4,cont))
    button1.pack()
    button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button3.pack()


class PageThree(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    title=tk.Label(self,text="Image Parameters")
    title.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    label1=tk.Label(self,text="How many images in a set").pack()
    entry1=tk.Entry(self)
    entry1.insert(0,"0.0")
    entry1.pack()

    label2=tk.Label(self,text="How many pixels in the X direction").pack()
    entry2=tk.Entry(self)
    entry2.insert(0,"0.0")
    entry2.pack()

    label3=tk.Label(self,text="How many pixels in the y direction").pack()
    entry3=tk.Entry(self)
    entry3.insert(0,"0.0")
    entry3.pack()

    button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Run", command=lambda: controller.GetNumbers(entry1,entry2,entry3,controller))
    button2.pack()

    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button1.pack()

class FinalPage(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

    label2=tk.Label(self,text="DONE")
    label2.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button2.pack()


class HelpPage(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

    label2=tk.Label(self,text="Help Page")
    label2.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button2.pack()



app=Application()
app.mainloop()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please edit your code down into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we don't have to sift through ~250 lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple fix is to use a lambda when setting the command property of the help button in `StartPage`.

You are currently calling the function `controller.show_frame(HelpPage)` at the point you call `tk.Button`, whereas you probably intended to call it at the point the button is pressed.

So instead of

```
button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Help", command=controller.show_frame(HelpPage))
```

use

```
button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Help", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HelpPage))
```

Like you have in other places in the code.